# Would Child/Grand Children Product Categories, with the same name, cause an issue with Search Engines?

Tags: seo, search-results

I am currently building the site structure of an eCommerce Arts & Crafts store.  One of the Parent Categories is:

- 'Wall Decor'

Within this Parent Category, there are 2 Child Categories:

- Paintings
- Photographs

Within each of these Child Categories, there are Grand Children Categories, such as:

- Forest
- Sea
- Jungle

As a result, the following URLs have been generated:

> 1. www.example.com/wall-decor/paintings/forest/
> 2. www.example.com/wall-decor/paintings/sea/
> 3. www.example.com/wall-decor/paintings/jungle/
> 4. www.example.com/wall-decor/photographs/forest/
> 5. www.example.com/wall-decor/photographs/sea/
> 6. www.example.com/wall-decor/photographs/jungle/

Personally, I feel there is nothing wrong with this approach to organising the site's products.  Photographs of Forest and Paintings of a Forest have their own place.

I am wondering if search engines would recognise that these are separate unique pages, from on page content and the URL structure as a whole, or would search engines simply look at the Grand Child Category/Category Page Title in isolation and assume that one of these Grand Children Categories is a duplicate?

Comment: Your URLs are fine. SEs put little weight on the URL. Your page can be about turtle doves with a URL of /pizza/new-york/blind/nuns/with-worts/ and users who want information on turtle doves will find your page assuming you have written good and valuable content. The URL is a signal and not exclusionary. Create URLs that make sense and stop freaking out! Please. Said with brotherly love. Cheers!!

Comment: My point is this. It is important to send good and proper signals of course. However, these are of little to no value compared to expertly written content. LSI favors well written content over any and all other signals. Do what is right for your users. Any URL should indicate what a page is about. You are on the right track. Please do not gnat's @$$ the details beyond the good work you have already done. Otherwise your antacid bill will be far too high for the payoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines will identify that all of your grandchildren URLs are different URLs and therefore should have different pages on them.

Each URL has 2 of the 3 same keywords, but not all 3 keywords are the same.

Search engines will crawl all or many of these pages, especially if there is unique content on each of them. When a person is looking to buy a framed picture of a sea photograph, Google may send that person to the page "photographs/sea/", and it's not going to send the user to the page "photographs/forest/". It will send people looking for forest photosgraphs to that page instead. It will also differentiate between the words photograph and painting and understand the difference. Ranking these pages assumes that your pages have great content for the keywords that you are targeting in your URLs, and that the content is completely related to those keywords.

Your URL structure looks great and you should have no problems with it.